# Editing of txt files not saving when I concatenate them

Tags: python, append, text-files

I am fairly new to programming, so bear with me!
We have a task at school which we are made to clean up three text files ("Balance1", "Saving", and "Withdrawal") and append them together into a new file. These files are just names and sums of money listed downwards, but some of it is jumbled. This is my code for the first file Balance1:

```
with open('Balance1.txt', 'r+') as f:

    f_contents = f.readlines()
    # Then I start cleaning up the lines. Here I edit Anna's savings to an integer.
    f_contents[8] = "Anna, 600000"

    # Here I delete the blank lines and edit in the 50000 to Philip.
    del f_contents[3]
    del f_contents[3]
```

In the original text file Anna's savings is written like this: "**Anna, six hundred thousand**" and we have to make it look clean, so its rather "**NAME, SUM (as integer)**. When I print this as a list it looks good, but after I have done this with all three files I try to append them together in a file called "Balance.txt" like this:

```
filenames = ["Balance1.txt", "Saving.txt", "Withdrawal.txt"]
with open("Balance.txt", "a") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            contents = infile.read()
            outfile.write(contents)
```

When I check the new text file "Balance" it has appended them together, but just as they were in the beginning and not with my edits. So it is not "cleaned up". Can anyone help me understand why this happens, and what I have to do so it appends the edited and clean versions?

Comment: Write your modifications to new files and then attempt to append those new files. It appears you are making changes to the original files but not saving them.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part, where you do the "editing" of `Balance`.txt` file, this is what happens:

1. You open the file in read mode
2. You load the data into memory
3. You edit the **in memory** data

And voila.

You never persisted the changes to any file on the disk. So when in the second part you read the content of all the files, you will read the data that was originally there.

So if you want to concatenate the edited data, you have 2 choices:

1. Pre-process the data by creating 3 final correct files (editing `Balance1.txt` and persisting it to another file, say `Balance1_fixed.txt`) and then in the second part, concatenate: `["Balance1_fixed.txt", "Saving.txt", "Withdrawal.txt"]`. Total of 4 data file openings, more IO.
2. Use only the second loop you have, and correct the `contents` before writing it to the `outfile`. You can use `readlines()` like you did first, edit the specific line and then use `writelines()`. Total of 3 data file openings, less IO than previous option